# How to get git producing output to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, git, output, stdout

I wanted to write the output of `git clone` to a file using

```
git clone https://github.com/someRepository > git_clone.file
```

But instead I get the output displayed/updated in the terminal like

```
Cloning to 'someRepository' ...
remote: Counting objects: 2618, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 2618 (delta 2), reused 12 (delta 1), pack-reused 2603
Received objects: 100% (2618/2618), 258.95 MiB | 4.39 MiB/s, Done.
Resolving Differences auf: 100% (1058/1058), Done.
Check Connectivity ... Done.
```

But the file `git_clone.file` is generated but remains empty.

My original goal was to bypass the output of `git` into a function (see [my question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988403/bash-pass-command-output-to-function-in-realtime)). But now I realized `git` doesn't even seem to produce the output to `stdout` really but somehow different since nothing is written to the file.

**How can I get this displayed output from `git` in order to redirect it to a file/function?**

---

**EDIT**

The proposed redirection of `stderr` (and `stdout`) did not solve the problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/someRepository 2> git_clone.file
git clone https://github.com/someRepository &> git_clone.file
git clone https://github.com/someRepository > git_clone.file > 2>&1
```

all gave me the same result: only the line

```
Cloning to 'someRepository' ...
```

appears in `git_clone.file`

---

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

Why do I need this?

As explained in [my other question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988403/bash-pass-command-output-to-function-in-realtime) I wrote a custom progress bar always at the bottom of the output my scripts. (I use it in multible scripts but) The [script](https://gist.github.com/Yolo-Jerome/e7e32f5c588f4209b362bff2f120d2e1) in this case migrates a lot of (until now 107) git repositories from github to our own Gitlab-Server and repairs the Git LFS support which usually is lost without it.

So I would like to still see all the output of git but also would like to have my progress bar working at the bottom of the output in the terminal.

Comment: Did you try `git clone https://github.com/someRepository > git_clone.file 2>&1`?

Comment: `>file 2>&1` equals `&>file` in modern `bash`, in case someone wonders.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for your help!

---

I just have found the solution:

#### Part 1

(Thanks to the [answer of dessert](https://askubuntu.com/a/989017/423684))
`git` by design does never write to `stdout` but `stderr`. So I needed to redirect `stderr`, too, in order to get the output using

```
git clone XYZ &> git_clone.file
```

#### Part 2

Anyway this wasn't enough and I only received the "uninteresting" part of the output to the file but not the lines of the progress I really wanted.

Doing further reserach again in [`man git-clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) I realized there exists an option

```
--progress
        progress status is reported on the standard error stream by 
        default when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is 
        specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard 
        error stream is not directed to a terminal.
```

Though I'ld think it actually was already attached to a terminal, this now seems to force git to write the lines of the progress part I'm most interested in finally to `stderr` as well so I can now get them using

```
git clone --progress XYZ &> git_clone.file
```

Comment: When you redirect stderr to a file, it is now attached to that file, and not a terminal.

Comment: This works, if we want to keep the history as kind of log, it can end to
&>> git_clone.file

Comment: for some reason this does not work with `git fsck`, the lines like `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.` are not visible in the logfile.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` uses `stderr` for the output, so just write *that* to the file:

```
git clone https://github.com/someRepository 2>git_clone.file
```

Alternatively you could redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` – that's not necessary in this particular, but this way you make sure *every* output produces by the command gets redirected:

```
git clone https://github.com/someRepository &>git_clone.file
```

---

In the case of `git clone` obviously there's a different output if you redirect it, the whole progress information running through in the terminal is not included in an output file. That's by design and IIRC you can't easily change that behaviour directly, **however** if you need the output in another script you may very well *pipe* it to it, which works just fine and gives you all the output:

```
git clone https://github.com/someRepository | cat
```

Inside your script you can get `stdin` with `-`, e.g. `cat -` to print `stdin` to `stdout` – see here for more: [How to write a script that accepts input from a file or from stdin?](https://superuser.com/q/747884/748149) and [How to read from a file or stdin in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6980090/6164712).

Comment: Both only gave me the very first line: `tail git_clone.file` -> `Cloning to 'someRepository' ... `

Comment: I put my script onto gitsts.github.com as example. (see the **BACKGROUND INFORMATION** I added to my question)

Comment: Hm I don't understand you 100% but I think it is still the same problem also with the pipe. I tried now `git clone XYZ |& tee git_clone.file` but I get the same "oneliner" result. I also tried `git clone -v ...` and this produces some more lines but the "interresting part" still is not written. Since the script will most of the type be busy downloading or uploading stuff during git ofcourse it would be most neccessary to show the progressbar during those times .. I'm after this like 3 weeks now ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort! I just found the solution (see my answer). Anyway I wouldn't have figured this out without knowing that I anyway have to get `stderr` since `git` only writes to it instead of `stdout`