# Couldn't able to store a output of awk command

Tags: command-line, bash, git, grep, awk

I have been trying to print git clone progress on more minimalistic way for my project.

**Aim**

Instead of printing a whole git clone output on screen

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 1845678, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (503/503), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.        
Receiving objects:  28% (54112/1845678), 10.10 MiB | 2.00 MiB/s
```

I want to abstract the lengthy lines of git output and just want to output the realtime progress of clone in the given below format

```
Cloning [$percentage]
```

**What I have got so far**

```
git clone --progress https://somerepo 2>&1 |tee gitclone.file | tr \\r \\n | total="$(awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')" | echo "$total"
```

Note: Since git clone only returns to stderr stream, I have redirected it to stdout stream. Even with the redirection I faced few issues, so I used progress option on git command.

I wanted to store output on the file (for debugging script) without disturbing stdout stream, so I used tee command. Since git clone returns `\r` instead of `\n`, I have replaced it to capture the output in proper manner. For more info on this part you can take a look at this question and its answer [Git produces output in realtime to a file but I'm unable to echo it out in realtime directly in a while loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990259/git-produces-output-in-realtime-to-a-file-but-im-unable-to-echo-it-out-in-realt)

Then I pick a line which has the keyword Receiving objects and print/store third keyfield value of that line.

**What is my problem**

My command is working fine if I am not storing output of awk and just printing it on screen:

```
git clone --progress https://somerepo 2>&1 |tee gitclone.file | tr \\r \\n | awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}'
```

But, I am unable to store the awk output in a shell variable and echo it back:

```
git clone --progress https://somerepo 2>&1 |tee gitclone.file | tr \\r \\n | total="$(awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')" | echo "$total"
```

So what could be a possible solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As the [bash manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bash.1.html) says:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

So, the output saved in the `total` variable is lost when the sub-shell exits. You can see this if you run this:

```
git clone --progress https://somerepo |& tee gitclone.file \
| tr \\r \\n | { total="$(awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')" ; \
 echo "$total" ; }
```

Since the variable `total` is lost after the above command line (i.e. pipe of commands) is finished, you should put the whole line into the "*command substitution*" parentheses like this:

```
total=$(git clone --progress https://somerepo |& tee gitclone.file | tr \\r \\n | awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')
echo "$total"
```

---

However, if you want the pipeline (starting with the `git` command) to be run in the background, then you have to redirect `awk`'s output to a file and later read that file. For example:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
git ... >"$tmpfile" &
# ...
# Do other stuff...
# ...
wait # for background process to complete.
total=$(cat "$tmpfile")
rm "$tmpfile"
echo "$total"
```

---

<sup>A hint: To redirect *stdout* and *stderr* of the `git` command to the `tee` command you can use the `|&` shorthand like this: `git clone --progress https://somerepo |& tee gitclone.file |` ...</sup>

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for time and efforts. But i am still not getting the output through total variable.Since i need to run perform this operation i have ran ur suggested command in background like below.

total=$(git clone --progress https://somerepo 2>&1 |tee gitclone.file  | tr \\r \\n | awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')&
echo "$total"

So is there any other way we i could try.

Comment: @EswarReddy remove the `&` - if you send it to the background, the whole thing will be done in a subshell and the parent shell won't see changes in the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion muru.I totally agree with you. But if i run this command on foreground i won't get terminal until the clone is completed right?. I need to do clone and print the progress on the same terminal. So can i pipe the echo command. like this

total=$(git clone --progress https://somerepo 2>&1 |tee gitclone.file  | tr \\r \\n | awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}')|echo "$total

Comment: Your requirement is not clear: You need to run the command in the background, but obtain the value in `total` ___when___? You cannot do this as long as the command is not finished. Please, [edit] your question and make it more clear.

Comment: Hello Fed,
I have editied my question aim part.Please havea look at it

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with git's output.
I does not complete new lines while rewriting the "Receiving objects:" line.

You can tell this is the case by looking at the output of

```
GIT_FLUSH=1 git clone --progress $repo 2>&1 | cat -bu
```

You will not see line numbers after the first occurance of the "Receiving" line. Here is an example where i pipe the output into "od" to make the \r and \n visible:

```
0000200                   \n                       4  \t   R   e   c   e
0000220    i   v   i   n   g       o   b   j   e   c   t   s   :        
0000240        0   %       (   1   /   1   1   0   3   8   )  \r   R   e
0000260    c   e   i   v   i   n   g       o   b   j   e   c   t   s   :
0000300                0   %       (   4   9   /   1   1   0   3   8   )
0000320    ,       8   .   8   8       M   i   B       |       2   .   8
0000340    4       M   i   B   /   s  \r
```

A program that reads input line by line (like awk) will not see those lines until git is finished.

Comment: Ya....if possible, can you suggest me a possible workaround.

Comment: You could try changing RS (the input record separator in AWK) from newline to carriage return: `BEGIN { RS="\r" }`

Answer (score 0):

You've fundamentally got a pipeline buffering issue. The input and/or output buffers used by the programs in the pipeline are too big. Fortunately there is a way to tell each program in the pipeline to buffer only one line.

This is the program you need:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/unbuffer.1.html.

It's installed by default in Ubuntu Desktop, I think, but if not:

```
sudo apt install expect
```

Then you can include the `unbuffer` command in your pipeline to solve the problem:

```
REPO_URL = https://something or git@something
unbuffer git clone --progress $REPO_URL 2>&1 | \
  unbuffer  -p tr \\r \\n | \
  { awk '/Receiving objects/{print $3}' ;  echo "$total" ; }
```

It prints 0%, 1%, ...100%, then because "total" is the last of those, prints 100% again, and it does so as the progress progresses, not all at the end or in large chunks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).